# Essential problem when defining conditional expectation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

According to

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation, it is not possible to compute integrals of the form;

$\int X dP_{H}$.

Where $dP_{H}$ is the restriction of $P$.

I have a hard time seeing where the shoe does not fit. The "restriction" should have a value for each set since it has a value in some superset.

Is there a problem because X might take values in some Borel set which does not have well defined preimage or is the problem that we might divide by zero. If the latter is the case then the measure $dP_{H}$
is not only a restriction but a rescaled restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final paragraph is on the right track. The problem is the pre-image of an open set under $X$ may not be in $H$. That is there might be an open set $U$ such that $$X^{-1}(U)\notin H.$$ In this case we say that $X$ is not $H$-measurable, and $\int X\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}_H$ is not defined since the Lebesgue integral is only defined for measurable functions.

To give some intuition for this, suppose $F$ is a measurable set which is not in $H$, and $X=\mathbf{1}_F$ is the *indicator* of $F$. From the way the Lebesgue integral is defined:
$$\int X\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}=\int \mathbf{1}_F\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{P}(F)$$
But since $F\notin H$, $\mathbf{P}_H(F)$ is not defined, and therefore neither is $\int X\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}_H$.

Comment: Hence $X$ forces us to go outside the algebra where the restricted measure does not exist? This would also hold having just the old measure $P$ tho right? Since the problem is the algebras ability the distingiush which mess up things in the end. Say $X$ takes two values in $A$ one which is in some non allowed Borel. Then we need to factor this set into the two pices in order to use either $P$ when forming the integral.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are are saying @user8321 but, if your point is that there may be functions $f$ which are not measurable relative to the original $\sigma$-algebra of the space, then you are right. For such functions  $\int f d\mathbf{P}$ is not defined. We do not call such functions *random variables* though.

Comment: Nono, I am saying that we dont really need to use the restriction of $P$ inorder to run into problems. We also cant compute the integrals$\int_{A} X dP$ if we only are allowed to use the smaller algebra. $X$ is still not measurable

Comment: Or did I confuse myself now? I think I got it..since when defing the conditional we assign the avrage for all sets $A$ and then we dont run into this problem since it is not possible to divide $A$ in to some smaller sets

Comment: "We also cant compute the integrals $\int_A X dP$ if we only are allowed to use the smaller algebra. X is still not measurable." I think this is confused. It would help if you explicitly stated (at least to yourself) what assumptions you are making about A, X and P. Note P is defined with respect to some $\sigma$-algebra to begin with (call it $\mathscr{F}$). If $X$ is a random variable then it is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable. If $A\in\mathscr{F}$ then $\int_A X dP=\int X\mathbf{1}_A dP$ is well-defined and if $A\in H$ then $A\in \mathscr{F}$ (since $H\subseteq \mathscr{F}$ ).